# SWRevealViewController-viewDidDisappear not calling when come from FrontViewController to Menupage

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

I use the `SWRevealViewController` to add a sidebar menu in my app. One of my menu element is DataList. When i click on DataList in menu page, It opens DataList page (via custom `SWRevealViewController` segue). When i click on menu button in *DataListpage* i am navigating to Menu page. Here

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:YES];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Methods are not calling in *DataListPage* when Navigate from *DataListPage* to Menu.

Because i have a `tableview` in *DataListPage* i want to save the scroll position.

Comment: have u show ur screens or storyboard,

Comment: I have followed this tutorial(http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/). My screens are looking exact as this tutorial shows

Comment: When i click on Tableviewcell in DataList page it is navigating to DataListDetail page. Here viewDidDisappear and viewWillDisappear methods are calling. But above methods are not calling when i come to menu page from DataListPage by clicking menu button

Comment: no need of view disappear ,etc. if u use SWL, u need to give the proper connection of SWLReveal name

Comment: Can you please explain little bit more

Comment: Swreveal view controller shows a table view on the side of the view controller... when i select a table row..the table is dismissed and a the seque creates a new view controller @user3373798